# Registering a marriage with non-EU citizen

Tags: eu-citizens, marriage, greece

I am a Romanian citizen and my husband is Nepali. We recently got married in Nepal, but now want to move to Greece. I have lived and worked in Greece and I also have a registration certificate from their immigration.

- As we want to move directly to Greece now, can I register our marriage in Greece or I have to do it in Romania where my permanent address is?
- If I go back to Romania and he wants to fly directly to Greece and meet me there, can he apply for a visa to Greek embassy with our marriage certificate and can he also apply for a 5 years residence permit in Greece so that we can settle down there?

The information I have is that first I need to register the marriage (but where, Romania or Greece, as I also have registration certificate from Greece?), then I have to send him the documents do that he can apply to Greek embassy for visa and then he can also apply for a 5 years residence permit in Greece, is that correct?

Comment: Flagged for migration to the expatriation website.

Comment: I don't know much about that and won't be able to provide an answer but I think it could be useful to add some information about your situation to get a better answer. Are you currently living and working in Greece? Or have you only lived there in the past? And, in that case, for how long? Were you until recently a permanent resident in Greece and do you want to resume that status or what's this “registration certificate” about?

Comment: If that's not the case, I would think that you first need to find work in Greece to ensure your husband qualifies for a residence permit as member of the family of an EU citizen but in the current context, it seems a bit difficult. Or do you have enough money to reside in Greece anyway?

Comment: No I were not recently a permanent resident in Greece , I have worked there for 3 months that's why I have this registration certificate, but if find s new job in Greece and rent a flat there will my husband qualify for a 5 years residence permit? And also can I register the marriage directly in Greece or I have to do it Romania ?

Comment: Or what's the case if I'm newly registered and working in Greece for a month for instance ? And also if I come back to Romania now, can he apply on his own to Greek embassy for a visa , thanks a lot

Comment: I have no idea about the marriage (I hope someone else will be able to help with that!) but in any case if you are not a worker, permanent residence, or have enough financial means to qualify for residence as non-economically person, you might not be able to sponsor your husband visa/permit.

Comment: The rule is simple: If you have work in Greece, your husband can live there with you. If you don't have work but live in Greece it's more complicated but it might still be possible. If you don't live in Greece, he has no right to go there based on EU rules. And as soon as you leave the country, he would usually lose his right to be there as well. In all cases, *you* have a right to live with your family, your husband only has indirect rights. In practice, this “registration certificate” might or might not help but it does not really open any rights in and of itself.

Comment: Yes I can prove that I'm worker through a work contract from a Greek employer and also prove that I reside there through registration certificate issued from Greek authorities, so in that case he might be able to qualify for a residence permit, right? Thanks for your time

Comment: As long as you are working, yes, it should be fine. Only reason I mentioned this is that I was under the impression you had left your job in Greece to come back to Romania. In any case, you should add all these details to your question so that someone who knows Greece better than myself can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance. Hope someone else would be able to clarify the rest of the issues.

Comment: @Relaxed Correction: if OP doesn't live in Greece, she does have the right to travel there *with her husband* for up to 90 days, with no need to show financial means.

Comment: @phoog Obviously and that's useful to highlight this as well but comments only offer limited space and the whole discussion was about settling down so I'd call that a complement rather than a correction.

Answer (score 2):

I am not specifically knowledgeable about your situation, but generally matters for citizens of EU countries, like registration of a marriage, happen in your own country. They are then honoured in all other EU countries.
So based on this, you should register the marriage in Romania.